# How can I check (without root permissions) if lazy write has been enabled for a filesystem

Tags: linux

Got a new machine but certain operations take a long time. I wanted to check if lazy write is enabled on a local filesystem. But the internet is silent about this issue.

How to check if lazy write is enabled on a local filesystem on LINUX without root permissions?

I cannot post the following as an answer, so I add it here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30286/can-i-configure-my-linux-system-for-more-aggressive-file-system-caching

Answer (score 0):

By "lazy write", I assume that you mean disk caching (aka buffered).

It happens automatically with Linux.  File system i/o sucks a** without a disk buffer.

The short answer is YES, it is enabled and going down this path is not needed.

`By default, the Linux kernel writes data to disk asynchronously. Writes are buffered (cached) in memory, and written to the storage device at the optimal time.`

Taken from [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/sync.htm) but there are thousands of other sites which will explain this.

The linux `sync` command forces a flush of the buffer so it is a good place to read about how this mechanism works.

Comment: I did not ask how to flush the disk!

Comment: Do you not get the connection between flushing the disk and "lazy write"?  I wasn't telling you how to flush a disk.. I was pointing out that Linux has disk buffering enabled by default and the `sync` command has good info on how it works (even if you don't use this command).  Did you not even read what I wrote?

Comment: @Señor_CMasMas
I was not looking for an explanation of how lazy write works.

Comment: `How to check if lazy write is enabled on a local filesystem on LINUX without root permissions?` .. you don't need to.  IT IS.  "Lazy Write" is disk caching.  What I keep trying to point you to is the fact that is IS enabled and there is no point in checking.  I don't care if you vote for my answer or not (I don't need the points).. I was just trying to help you.  Please don't rebut me again.. simply think that I am an idiot or whatever you want to believe and wait for someone else to chime in.

Comment: You will have more luck if you research Linux disk caching.